# Is there any way to convert string patterns as shown in the map below?

Tags: sql, regex, perl, sas

[image]

Trying to convert 'Currently' patterns in the above table to 'Turn It Into' patterns in the data set ...
Examples are shown in the next 2 columns for each one....
I tried different ways but I could not get required output ....
Here is the code to get the input data....

```
    data Current;
Input Currently :$40.;
Datalines;
HiKumar"^TM1()^",test
HiKumar"^TM2()^"
HiKumar^TM3()^HiKumar
HiKumar^f(‘VARNAME’).any(‘#’)^
HiKumar^f(‘VARNAME’)^
HiKumar^f(‘VARNAME’).get()==’#’^
HiKumar^f(‘VARNAME’)==’#’^
HiKumar^f(‘VARNAME’).toNumber()^
HiKumar^f(‘VARNAME’).toString()^
HiKumar^f(‘VARNAME’).toString().toLowerCase()^
HiKumar^f(‘VARNAME’).toString().toUpperCase()^
HiKumar^f(‘IFCONDITION’)?’THENTEXT’:’ELSETEXT’^
HiKumar<br>
HiKumar<br/>
HiKumar<br />
HiKumar^MobileHeader()^
HiKumar^MobileFooter()^
HiKumar<u>
HiKumar</u>
HiKumar&nbsp
;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with regular expressions. You'll need several; here's one to start.  (The quotation characters will probably be mucked up by the web browser and/or SAS, so I would recommend replacing those manually rather than trusting the copy/paste if they don't work at first).  This only identifies the fourth row, but similar regex's can be constructed for the other rows (and some you should be able to use for multiple rows).

```
data want;
set current;
rx_1 = prxparse("/\^f\(‘(\w*?)’\)\^/");
rc_1 = prxmatch(rx_1,currently);
if rc_1 ne 0 then have = prxposn(rx_1,1,currently);
run;
```

Comment: Hi Joe,Thanks for the answer...It worked fine and I'm trying to use PRXCHANGE instead of PRXPOSN....I have no clue about perl scripting . I would appreciate it if you send me the prxparse's for all rows in above table...Thanks,Sam.

Comment: Here is what I did.....But PRXCHANGE is not replacing the value...I'm not sure where I'm doing mistake...data Turned_PRX;
Set Current;
/*retain re; 
IF _N_ =1 THEN do;*/
rp = PRXPARSE ("/\^f\(‘(\w*?)’\)\^/");
rm = prxmatch(rp,currently);
/*end;*/
if rm ne 0 then have = prxposn(rp,0,currently);
if rm ne 0 then need = prxposn(rp,1,currently);
if rm ne 0 then exchange = PRXCHANGE ('s/rp/need/' ,-1, currently);
run;

Comment: Sampath, there is a lot of documentation on this subject.  I recommend using PRXPOSN as it uses capture groups, but PRXCHANGE is fine.  Please feel free to come back and post specific questions; if you tag them 'regex' then you will get help from regular expression folks as well as SAS folks.